# Getting the total length of multiple Vue.js data output

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

**TLDR;**

I have a Vue dropdown component that populates a list of selectable items.

```
               <dropdown-component inline-template>
                    <div>
          <!--Drop Label--><span v-on:click='showDropDown=!showDropDown' :class="{'active-menu': showDropDown, '': !showDropDown">{{someData.current.name1}} ({{someData.current.name2}}) {{someData.current.name3}}</span>
    <!-- Drop Menu List --><div v-if='showDropDown' v-cloak v-model="showDropDown">
                         <div>
                            <input type="text" v-model="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
                         </div>
              <!-- Data populated list --><div v-for='data in searchFilter'>
                               <span v-on:click='dataClicked(data)'>{{data.name1}} {{data.name2}} {{data.name3}}</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </dropdown-component>
```

When an item is selected, the dropdown label is updated to the selected values.

for instance I have some data returned that is searchable:

```
data: function(){
 return {
   someData: someDataReturned.things, //only filtering array of things
   search: ''
 }
}
```

the structure of my data set is:

```
{
 things: [{name1: value1, name2: value2},{name1: value1, name2: value2}],
 current: {name1: value1, name2: value2, name3: value3}
}
```

Then with this data set I have a computed filter for a search to work

```
computed: {
        searchFilter: function() {
            var _this = this;
            return this.someData.filter(function(obj){
                return obj.name1.toString().indexOf(_this.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            });
        }
```

The values can be different lengths and I'm trying to get a total count of all characters and truncate `{{name1}} {{name2}} {{name3}}` accordingly.

when an item is selected, I set the `current` values to update the label.

```
dataClicked: function(item) {
 someData.current.name1 = item.name1;
 someData.current.name2 = item.name2;
 someData.current.name3 = item.name3;
}
```

**HERE: ---**

I'm wanting to get the total length of the label and truncate with `filters`

Something like:

```
filters: {
    truncate: function(val){ return val.substring(0,30) }
}
```

Yet I only want to truncate `name1` and `name2` depending on the total length of the text combined. length of name1 + name2 + name3 , then truncate name1 and name2 accordingly.

Is there a way to do this in Vue with `filters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to pass the whole object to the filter.

In the template:

```
{{ someData.current | truncate }}
```

Then in your `filters`:

```
truncate (current) {
    var name1 = current.name1,
        name2 = current.name2,
        name3 = current.name3,
        totalLength = name1.length + name2.length + name3.length;

    if (totalLength > 30) {
        // Inset appropriate truncation here
        name1 = name1.slice(0, 4);
        name2 = name2.slice(0, 4);
    }

    return name1 + ' ' + name2 + ' ' + name3;
}
```

As written here it will just truncate `name1` and `name2` to 4 characters. You haven't given any details of the truncation rules you're looking to apply so I haven't attempted anything more sophisticated.

Comment: ^^ THIS. A perfect example of simplifying this. Thank you! I'm hoping I worded this question correctly to help others in similar scenarios.